# Full background image; content not scrolling

Tags: css

I have implemented a full, non scrolling background image with CSS. However, when the content itself overflows the page no scrollbars appear and the content cannot be seen. I have tried using various variations of "overflow: scroll" in a few of my divs but to no avail; scroll bars appear but they do not scroll, or do not scroll properly. I think there may be a structural problem with my divs but I'm not particularly experienced with CSS and couldn't find a thread similar to this on StackOverflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/YXp5p/

```
<body>

<div id="bg">
    <img src="images/background.jpg">
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        thread #6bUp0
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="post">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec erat ante, placerat accumsan aliquam at, rhoncus eget nunc.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

body{
    margin: 0px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: helvetica, times;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#bg {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-50%; 
    left:-50%;
    width:200%; 
    height:200%;
}
#bg img {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    margin:auto; 
    min-width:50%;
    min-height:50%;
}

#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top:0%; 
    left:18%;
    width: 59%;
    height:200%;
    padding: 0%;
}

#header {
    background: url(images/header.gif) repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height:29px;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}   

#sidebar {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    right: 3%;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

#post{
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `background-attachment:fixed` not `position:fixed` you can achieve what you want like this:

```
body{
    background-image:url('images/background.jpg');
    background-position:center top;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: helvetica, times;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Oh, and remove the:

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="images/background.jpg">
</div>
```

part of your document.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I did what you said but the image comes out tiled rather than the previous implementation, which made it stretch to fit. When the content overflows no scroll bars appear either. Any ideas?